# Extract email from a text file

Tags: regex, email

What is the right perl regulat expression to extract email adress from a text file when it is written under this form

someone at something.domainextension  OR someone.someone at something.domainextension

Is it possible to have a regular expression that convert these adresses into normal email adresses ?

Thanx in Advance

Comment: This is a duplicate question and you will find plenty of answers in stackoverflow. Remember though that proper email validation cannot be done using regular expressions and it shouldn't be done. see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @Aleksi - Not exactly. He states that the email addresses in the file are not in RFC 5322 format but "someone at something.domainextension OR someone.someone at something.domainextension". So this can easily be solved by regex and the typical email-regex caveats do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ruby, but it will be the same in Perl

```
>> "someone.someone at something.domainextension".sub(/\bat\b/,"@").gsub(/\s+/,"")
=> "someone.someone@something.domainextension"
```

basically just substitute "at" with "@" and remove all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the below code can accomplish your task.  However it will not work if your email address is split across lines and it also will give you a false positive if you have only an " at something.com"  I could make this code a bit more specific to handle your situation if you could post some sample data from your data set.

As noted in the comment above, this will not find absolutely every email address that is valid under RFC whatever, but I think it should handle your issue.

```
my @lines_from_file; #holds our test info

#load the test info
$lines_from_file[0] = 'this is some text.  We like to type to someone at somthing.com but sometimes';
$lines_from_file[1] = 'they go by someone.someone at something.com just to confuse us and hey you never';
$lines_from_file[2] = 'know, maybe they use parens like (someone at something.com).';
$lines_from_file[3] = 'make sure we do not find someone at .com. or someone something.com or someone at somethingcom';

my @all_email_addresses; #holds all found email addresses


#foreach line in the file
foreach my $line (@lines_from_file){
    while($line =~ /([0-9a-zA-Z.]+)    #capture any number or letter or dot 1 or more times
                    \sat\s             #" at "
                    ([0-9a-zA-Z.]+     #capture any number or letter or dot 1 or more times
                    \.                 #dot
                    \w{2,4})           #com or net or us or tv or info etc., 
                   /xg){
        #everytime the line matches an email save the email in email form
        push @all_email_addresses, "$1\@$2" ;
    }

}

print "@all_email_addresses";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:(\w+)\.)?(\w+)\s+at\s+(\w+)\.(\w+)$/
```

This won't capture all email addresses, just those of the form you supplied.